# ForbiddenAttributesError, Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I allow users to login using Facebook and Google using OmniAuth, also I allow them to create accounts using their emails. Everything is working fine except for the part in which the users are able to update their account information.

I added a field called username, in which the sign_up and sign_in handles Ok, for the update I don't want to require the user enter password if he is signed in using facebook but I keep getting ForbiddenAttributesError.

here is the code I wrote.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?    

  def update
    @provider = Provider.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    email_changed = current_user.email != params[resource_name][:email]
    is_omniauth_account = @provider.blank?

    successfully_updated = if is_omniauth_account
      resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
    else
      resource.update_without_password(params[resource_name])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      render_with_scope :edit
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password) }
  end

  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
  private :resource_params
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the method defined to handle the [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), but you aren't using it in your `update` action.

Give this a try:

```
successfully_updated = if is_omniauth_account
  resource.update_with_password(resource_params)
else
  resource.update_without_password(resource_params)
end
```

Comment: it could work out, but I figured out another solution based on Devise documentation. Please checkout the answer I inserted thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked out, but I still have issue I am not sure if it is a good practice to remove a parameter at run time

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def update
    @provider = Provider.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    email_changed = current_user.email != resource_params[:email]
    is_omniauth_account = !@provider.blank?
    successfully_updated = if is_omniauth_account
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
      resource.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))      
    else
      resource.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def create
    super
    UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver

  end

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password) }
  end
end
```